# Intuition behind exponential sum convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, intuition

My textbook states without proof that the summation:

$$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x!} e^{ax}$$

converges for all real $a$. I am trying to understand this. I assume the reasoning is that the factorial term (which is decreasing in the tail as $x \to \infty$) dominates the exponential (which could be increasing in the tail if $a>0$), but I lack intuition for why the former would dominate.

I'd appreciate an explanation of any sort -- intuitive, formal, or both.

Comment: Intuitively, $n!$ "behaves like $n^n$ (this is [not exactly correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but gives you a rough idea of the speed of convergence). So, for any fixed $\alpha$, $\alpha^n/n!$ will "behave like" $(a/n)^n$, and this goes to zero way faster than any inverse polynomial. Hence the convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formal way to show that this converges is the ratio test: $$\frac{e^{a(x+1)}/(x+1)!}{e^{ax}/x!}=\frac{x!e^{ax}e^{a}}{(x+1)x!e^{ax}}=\frac{e^{a}}{x+1}\to 0<1$$ as $x\to+\infty$.